# How to query netstat to find PID for specific local address in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file, netstat

I frequently start server on local address `[::]:8080`. To terminate server I need `PID` fetched from `netstat -aon`.

To terminate this server I do `taskkill /F /PID <found pid>`

I want to create windows batch file that can find PID and apply it in call `taskkill /F /PID <found pid>`

How can I create such batch file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my PC there could be a UDP or TCP connection and they require slightly different code:
Test this to see if one of the taskkill commands looks right and remove `echo` to enable the taskkill command.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^|find " [::]:8080 " ^|find /i " TCP " ') do echo taskkill /F /PID %%a

for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^|find " [::]:8080 " ^|find /i " UDP " ') do echo taskkill /F /PID %%a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "port=8080"

    for /f "tokens=1,4,5" %%a in (
        'netstat -aon ^| findstr /r /c:"[TU][CD]P[^[]*\[::\]:%port%"'
    ) do if "%%a"=="UDP" (taskkill /F /PID %%b) else (taskkill /f /PID %%c)

    endlocal
```

Use `findstr` to retrieve only the needed record, tokenize it using the `for` command to get the PID column (4th for UDP, 5th for TCP) and kill the task